# Tableau axis dynamically set on formula

Tags: formula, axis, tableau-api, axes

Is it possible to set fixed axis on formula?

I have several countries plotted in different graph

```
UK, FR, ES,
```

I would like to be able to set fixed end dynamically according to the selection?

Many thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question is different. I would like to set the axis fixed according to the selection. for example 
if [country] ="UK" Fixed ends at 20,0000, if [country] ="FR" Fixed ends at 10,0000, if [country] ="IT" Fixed ends at 5,0000,

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, you can click on measures and use fixed axis option..
If this doesn't resolve, please attach a screenshot or please elaborate your issue.

HTH..

Answer (score -1):

As of v9.2 you can fix one end of axis and keep the other one automatic or independent